# Deducing the selected overloaded function type for given argument types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, overload-resolution

Is it possible to determine the function type of the candidate that overload resolution would select given an overload set and an argument list? For example, given:

```
char* f(int);
int f(char*);
```

I would like to be able to write something like:

```
overload<f, short>::type x;
```

to declare a variable `x` of type `char* (*)(int)`.

Is this possible? My first instinct was to write something like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct overload {
    template<typename Ret>
    static auto deduce(Ret (*fptr)(Args...)) -> decltype(fptr);
};
```

...but this can't handle non-exact matches (i.e. `decltype(overload<int>::deduce(f))` works, but `decltype(overload<short>::deduce(f))` does not).

Comment: I don't think this can be done in C++, you can get the return type, but not the type of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

C++14 generic lambdas to the rescue:

```
#define wap_function(f) \
   [](auto&&... args){ return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

Note that this gem also solves the problem of first-class function templates:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto add(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

std::accumulate(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0, wrap_function(add));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is stripped from [Convert overloaded function to template functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340016/convert-overloaded-function-to-template-functor).

Problem is, you cannot plugin an overloaded function to a template, because its type must be known, thus define a macro:

```
#define overload_set(f, f_set) \
    template <typename ...Args> \
    struct f_set { \
        typedef decltype(f(std::declval<Args>() ...)) return_type; \
        typedef return_type (*) (Args ...) type; \
    };
```

Define the struct for every function you want to use:

```
overload_set(f, f_set)
```

Now the function pointer type can be accessed with:

```
typedef typename f_set<int>::type f_int;
typedef typename f_set<char *>::type f_charptr;
```